# comparing user input to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have to create a program that lets a user input what courses they have taken(one at a time), and compare it to a dictionary of "courses" with the pre-requisites and print what courses that student is eligible to take. I am not sure on how to compare the user input to the dictionary to print what courses they can take. Here is what I have so far

```
print "Enter a course(0 to quit): "
courses = raw_input()
d = {150:[150],
     161:[161],
     162:[161],
     231:[162],
     241:[161],
     251:[251],
     260:[150],
     300:[241],
     303:[162],
     304:[162],
     307:[162],
     353:[231],
     385:[353],
     355:[231],
     461:[303,304,307,231],
     475:[303,304,307],
     480:[470]
     }



while courses =! '':

if courses in d.keys():
    print("You have taken: ", courses)
if courses == 0:
    break
```

Comment: Be really careful when posting Python code in questions.  The indentation is critical.  I edited your question and put what I think is ok, but double check.

Comment: You didn't really make a question, you gave what looks like an assignment description and a small piece of code.  I recommend you read [SO's help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's ok to ask about homework, but its better to do it by giving a description of what you're having problems with.

Comment: @NicWerner You should not modify edits if it is not for a better version. 2 people used their time to help you editing your question and you change it again to a non working version of the code. Please read the edits and understand them. And then, edit your code again so it is actually runable.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting input once. You need to get input in a loop:

```
d = {150:[150],161:[161],162:[161],231:[162],241:[161],251:[251],260:[150],300:[241],303:[162],304:[162],307:[162],353:[231],385:[353],355:[231],461:[303,304,307,231],475:[303,304,307],480:[470]}

prereqs = set()

while True:
    course = int(raw_input("Enter a course you have taken (0 to quit): "))
    if course == 0:
        break
    try:
        prereqs.update(d[course])
    except KeyError:
        print '\t\t\t\t\tHmm...I don\'t know that course'
```

In the while loop, we are getting input every iteration. If it is 0, we break out of the loop. If not, we try to lookup the course in the dict. If this fails, we print the "error" message. You should be able to take it from here(`prereqs` stores the courses that you have took in a set).